# Automatic updates only for major tools' version increases?

Tags: download, version, software-updates

When I have to automatically update my Linux system, I would like to update only the tools which have a significant version number increase, and not for each minor update. This is both to save network traffic, but especially to reduce my SSD wearing.

E.g.: today I am proposed to update 806 packages, most of which go from, e.g., version 3.1.0-6 to 3.1.0-8.

Is there the option to update only the tools with version x.y.z which increment their x or y values only?

And the option to update only the tools I use the most?

My current distribution is Manjaro/Arch, but this question is general and applies to every distribution.

Comment: Well, it is exactly the patch-level increases which often contain important security fixes, so I'm not sure that's an approach I would recommend. I know some distros flag security updates differently from regular updates, maybe that would be a useful thing to look at? (Maybe that's more for-pay enterprise ones, though.)

Comment: SSD wear from package upgrades is insignificant, unless you’re tracking development releases (and even then it’s not worth worrying about).

Comment: @StephenKitt - I would not say SSD wear is insignificant if I keep updating packages on a daily basis. Consider that no matter how small an update is, at least a whole block is rewritten, consuming one more of its limited write cycles.

Comment: Another example: today I could update Blender from version 17:2.80-2 to 17:2.80-8, for a totale download size of 44 MB. And I have never used it so far.

Comment: SSDs are rated for numbers of writes which far exceed what the vast majority of users will ever need over the lifetime of the drives, even if you upgrade packages every single day. I upgrade packages every day on SSDs, built software on them, build containers on them, store large amounts of data on them, even store swap on them, and yet my most worn-out drive is only at 28% of its rated lifetime writes, after nearly seven years of constant use.

Comment: And if you’re that worried about writes, you’d save more of them by not installing packages you don’t need in the first place ;-).

Comment: See [this four-year-old endurance comparison](https://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead/) for example: the first drive to die did so after 700 terabytes, which is over 16 million times the 44 megabytes of your Blender download.

Comment: OK, you convinced me in this regard. The question still applies for other possible reasons, e.g. minimize traffic on a mobile 3G network.